# How to make a link between a JSP page and an Alfresco activiti?

Tags: jsp, alfresco, activiti

I am new to `Alfresco` activiti and my problem in `Alfresco` is that I am not understanding how to make a link between a `JSP` and an `Alfresco` activiti.

Comment: I guess we are going to need more information. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Need more informations, do you need to connect your application with alfresco ??? what do you mean with Alfresco Activiti ???

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to connect to your `Alfresco` Repository

```
private static Session getSession(String serverUrl, String username, String password) {SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, serverUrl);
    params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
    if (repos.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server has no repositories!");
    }
    return repos.get(0).createSession();
}
```

you only have to add your `ServerUrl` , `Username` and a `Password` (in default it will be `admin` , `admin` )

Comment: Is it what you are looking for (there's many others method like create a file , upload a file ...)